# How to sort UITableview array data by time using swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to loading `JSON` data into `UITableview`. Here, JSON data I am getting from API with help of `Codable` and `Decodable` method. Now, I don’t have any ID to sort my list because I am using `dictionary` unordered. So, how to achieve this?

NOTE: `meeting_id` based need to sort my tableview data load.

**JSON Sample**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "meeting_id": "37",
            "title": "abc",
            "sort_key": "21:00",
        },
        {
            "meeting_id": "41",
            "title": "a1",
            "sort_key": "03:00",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Codable Structure**

```
struct Events: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: [Eventdata]
}

struct Eventdata: Codable {
    let meetingID, title, sort_key: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case meetingID = "meeting_id"
        case title
        case sortKey = "sort_key"
    }
}
```

**My Code Decoding**

```
var eventsData = [Eventdata]()

do {
          let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Events.self,  from: data)
          let status = decoder.status
              if status == true {
                      self.eventsData = decoder.data
                      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                            //self.Alert(Meesage: ServerValidation().servervalidation_msg)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        //self.Alert(Meesage: ServerError().servererror_msg)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why you need `asyncAfter`?

Comment: `meetingID` Should be `Int`. And that you can compare them

Comment: if you want to sort data by date-time then you can use timestamp in JSON data so it is easy to sort.

Comment: i can just sort model by  self.eventsData  = self.eventsData.sorted(by: { $0. timestamp > $1. timestamp })

Comment: @Kishan Suthar Thank you. Btw now I need to sort by meetingID.

Comment: @vpoltave Take a closer look and you will see that in his JSON file it is a String: ```"37"```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
self.eventsData = decoder.data
self.eventsData  = self.eventsData.sorted(by: { $0.meetingID > $1.meetingID })
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, if you compare `String`'s "1000" < "999" it's give you `true`

Comment: @Nguyen Hoan Thanks I will check it and update you here

Comment: @Nguyen Hoan can I use `sortKey` this key to sort?

Comment: @GongraMon you can do that, just change the type of sortKey to Double (convert 21:00 to Date and get timeIntervalSince1970) => you can use sortKey instead of meetingID